# There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Scaffolding failed. The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')' in VS 2022

Tags: entity-framework-core, code-generation, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Project type is asp.net MVC core. Adding a Razor View with or without Model I receive the following results:

There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Scaffolding failed. The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')'

Using VS2022 17.0.4 targeting .net 6.0 EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.1

I tried some of the remedies from the question that pops up on SO for VS2013:

1. cleaned out bin and obj folders and rebuilt
2. verified that all projects with EntityFrameWorkCore had the same version

BTW, adding a controller works.

Any help or guidance would be welcomed. This is a show stopper.

EDIT: I noticed that some or all of the projects in the solution were corrupted so I recreated project from scratch.  I was able to add two views and then I received the message as above, again. Also, as I was building the project again I tested by adding a Razor view before I made any changes to the template generated project (asp.net core MVC) and it worked.

Something is corrupting one or more of my projects, and I think it might be NuGet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will now go rebuild the project from scratch for a third time and observe better and more frequently as to when the add Razor view fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was recreating the solution from scratch I found the culprit.  ME!

I do not like the new style of Main entry points where the code just starts without a namespace or class definition such as follows:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So I rewrote the class Program and created Startup and attempted to refactor all the code from Program.  Obviously I did not do well.  This caused my problem with the failed add of a templated Razor view.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by uninstalling the nuget package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

[Reference](https://programmingcsharp.com/implement-identity-on-existing-asp-project/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got this error today while adding the Identity Scaffolded item to my existing Blazor server project.

[image]

I tried to add Identity Scaffolded item after updating the EF Core packages to 6.0.9 but unfortunately there seems to be some issue in the latest EF core packages.

So, I rolled back the EF Core packages from 6.0.9 to 6.0.8 and everything worked fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

download all packages the same version and cleaned up obj and bin file and rebuild your project. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and tried everything I could find to resolve it. - Made sure project would compile. Made sure all NuGet packages were the same version - 7.1. Looked for references to Microsoft.EntitiyFramework.Identity.

```
- No love.
```

Then I ran the latest Visual Studio updater to 17.4.3, I don't recall the version I as on, and we're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to created the scaffolding in a view project, but the all the Entity Framework installation had in other DAL project, then install the nugets in the view project and done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that when it was trying to execute the scaffolding it failed when it was downloading entity framework so I updated to the last version all entity framework nuggets and it worked.